# push does not work as I would expect it - why?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am experiencing a behavior of the `push` function that I don't get. Maybe someone could explain to me why Lisp behaves this way.

Supposed I define a list as a global variable, and then try to push a new value to it using the following code:

```
(defparameter *primes* '(3 5 7 11))
(push 2 *primes*)
```

Then `*primes*` is now `(2 3 5 7 11)`. So far, so good.

Now I try to do the same thing, but without the `*primes*` variable, i.e.:

```
(push 2 '(3 5 7 11))
```

The result is an error message:

> EVAL: 3 is not a function name; try using a symbol instead

Now I have two questions:

1. Why does this not work? I would expect that `push` returns the list `(2 3 5 7 11)`, why does this not happen? Where am I wrong?
2. Apart from that, I don't get the error message. What is Lisp trying to tell me with `3 is not a function name`? Of course, `3` is not a function name, but I don't try to call a function named `3` anywhere, do I?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you read the CL Hyperspec for [PUSH](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_push.htm#push), you will read that `push` expects a *place*.

A *place* is something like a variable, a structure slot, a class slot, an array access, or similar. Since Lisp uses linked cons cells for lists, it does not make sense to push something in front of a cons cell, without a reference for that.

So above is simple: **we can't push to a direct list.**

**Why this error message?**

*This gets a bit complicated...*

```
(push 2 '(3 5 7 11))
```

Is actually:

```
(push 2 (quote (3 5 7 11))
```

A function can be a place, it then needs a corresponding setter function. Here the setter is thought to be `(setf quote)` - that's right, Common Lisp can sometimes have *lists* as function names, not only symbols.

If we look at the macroexpansion of above:

```
? (pprint (macroexpand '(push 2 (quote (3 5 7 11)))))

(LET* ((#:G328 2) (#:G327 (3 5 7 11)) (#:G326 (CONS #:G328 '#:G327)))
  #:G327
  #:G326
  (FUNCALL #'(SETF QUOTE) #:G326 #:G327))
```

You can see that it tries to call the setter. But it also thinks that `(3 5 7 11)` is a Lisp form.

I give you an example, where it actually works, but we don't use `quote`, but a real accessor function:

```
CL-USER 40 > (let ((v (vector (list (list 'a 'b 'c) (list 'd 'e 'f))
                              (list (list 1 2 3)    (list 4 5 6)))))
               (print v)
               (push 42 (first (aref v 1)))
               (print v)
               (values))

#(((A B C) (D E F)) ((1 2 3) (4 5 6))) 
#(((A B C) (D E F)) ((42 1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
```

In above `first` is the getter and CL knows the corresponding *setter*. The form `(aref v 1)` is the call and returns the index 1 element of the vector. We are then pushing to the *first* list of the element.

Your call has a similar structure and `(3 5 7 11)` is at a similar position as `(aref v 1)`. The Lisp system says that in `(3 4 7 11)` then number `3` is not a valid function. Which is correct. But the real error was about the `push` operation. Since the macro could not detect the error, the error gets later detected in the macro expanded code.

Answer (score 1):

I have found only the emacs lisp manual [`push`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html), but I guess it behaves similar for Common Lisp

> — Macro: push element listname
>
> This macro creates a new list whose car is element and whose cdr is the list specified by listname, and *saves that list in listname*.

So it seems `push` is modifying its argument `listname`, which isn't possible with a literal list. To do what you have in mind, one would use `cons` instead.

To the second part `3 is not a function name`, I would say `push`, or some function inside it, tries to evaluate the literal list. Evaluating `(3 5 7 11)` means, call the function `3` with arguments `5 7 11`. Hence the error message.

---

Again from emacs, <kbd>Ctrl-h f push</kbd>

> push is a Lisp macro in `cl.el'.
>
> (push X PLACE)
>
> Insert X at the head of the list stored in PLACE.
>   Analogous to (setf PLACE (cons X PLACE)), though more careful about
>   evaluating each argument only once and in the right order.  PLACE may
>   be a symbol, or any generalized variable allowed by `setf'.

`setf` in turn allows `place` to be a

> symbolic references such as (car x) or (aref x i)

which explains, why `push` evaluates the second argument.

Comment: CLHS `push` reference: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm

Answer (score -1):

I think you need `CONS` in second case:

```
(cons 2 '(3 5 7 11)) => (2 3 5 7 11)
```

Comment: Any comment on minus?